# Migrating hosting of WCF Web Services to IIS problems

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis, .net-4.0

The team I work with has recently migrated from a self hosted setup to IIS hosting of thier web services.  The migration went 'smoothly' however we are now seeing some funny behaviour on our server.

If we make a simple request call from our client to our server to get some data from our DB everything works as expected.  If we make a call from our client to our server and then the server makes a call to a 3rd party service (hosted off site) then we're seeing a massive increase in response time.  A call like this used to take less than a few seconds, since migrating to IIS hosting the response time is over a few minutes.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?  Is it possible that we're having issues with credentials between the IIS hosted server and the 3rd party service?

Comment: Could be many things, first thing I'd try is doing a speed test from the hosted server to see what kind of downstream bandwidth is being given to you. Also try doing a traceroute from your hosted server to the 3rd party to see if there's something going on there. Since the 3rd party calls actually still work, I'm not inclined to believe there are authentication issues, as I imagine you'd be using some kind of shared key or standard login for such a service.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the bindings haven't changed and you are using the same service identity (i.e. Windows account) then you should get the same performance.

Have you checked whether the service is using static variables and/or multi-threading logic? You could be having resource contention problems with the proxy to the 3rd party service. You'll need to provide more detail about service to get a more specific recommendation.